# Use read-time conditionalization on several atoms

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to use Lisp's read-time conditionalization feature to merge two versions of my code, old and new. I have something like:

```
'(ant bee #+new cat #+new dog #+new eel fish)
```

so the old version is:

```
'(ant bee fish)
```

and the new version, when the feature **new** is defined, is:

```
'(ant bee cat dog eel fish)
```

Is there some way of writing this more succinctly, with only one occurrence of **#+new**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can also use a backquote, here's a solution that works in at least three Common Lisp implementations.  You can simply backquote the list, and then use the conditional before a comma-at spliced list:

```
CL-USER> `(a b #+new,@'(c d e) f)
(A B F)

CL-USER> (push :new *features*)
...

CL-USER> `(a b #+new,@'(c d e) f)
(A B C D E F)
```

In the documentation section [2.4.8.17 Sharpsign Plus](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dhq.htm), we read that (emphasis added):

> #+ operates by first reading the feature expression and then *skipping over the form* if the feature expression fails. While reading the test,
>   the current package is the KEYWORD package. Skipping over the form is
>   accomplished by binding *read-suppress* to true and then calling read.

There's no universal implementation of backquote, so I'm not absolutely certain that this is completely portable.  We're depending on the assumption that `,@<something>` will be read as *one form* so that it's what's skipped over. If it's possible for it to be processed as more than one form, this won't work.  I've tested it in Clozure CL, SBCL, and CLISP, and it works in all of those.

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this help:

```
#+new
(defvar *new-items* '(cat dog eel))
#-new
'(ant bee fish)
#+new
(append '(ant bee fish) *new-times*)
```

to be more portable? Not exactly one use of `#+new` but it makes its use less scattered.